# How to add a 'Business Year' condition to the AG Grid filter?

Tags: javascript, datagrid, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We use AG Grid and I can see that in the date filter we have 'This Week', 'This Quarter', 'This Month', 'This Year' etc.  But our year is a business year that runs from April to March.  How can I add that option to the filter?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the date filters that you list, I am fairly sure that you are using AdapTable - our AG Grid add-on.
If so, then you simply need to add a Custom Predicate in the AdapTableQLOptions section of AdapTable Options and make it available for all Date column filters.
Based on your question something like this should do the trick:

```
adaptableQLOptions: {
  customPredicateDefs: [
    {
       id: 'business_year',
       moduleScope: ['filter'],
       columnScope: { 
         DataTypes: ['Date'] 
       },
       label: 'Business Year',
       handler: ({ value, inputs }) => {
         const businessYearStart: Date = new Date(2022, 3, 1);
         const businessYeaEnd: Date = new Date(2023, 2, 31);
         return value >= businessYearStart && value <= businessYeaEnd;
       },
    },
  ],
}
```

This will make that filter appear in Quick Filter bar dropdown for all Column Filters.
See more at: https://docs.adaptabletools.com/guide/adaptable-ql-predicate-custom